# How to edit my query SQL Server to get result faster

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried a query on SQL Server using Java like this

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA1
WHERE Project NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Project  FROM DATA1 WHERE Resource = 'I-FINAL')
ORDER BY RECORDID DESC
```

It runs slowly for about 1 minutes.

But when I ran it with this query

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA1
ORDER BY RECORDID DESC
```

It was really fast about 100 ms. I guess my problem is `NOT IN` caused it. I do not know to make new query to get result faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try an exclusion join:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM DATA1 d
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT DISTINCT Project  FROM DATA1 WHERE Resource = 'I-FINAL'
    ) d0 ON d0.Project = d.Project
WHERE d0.Resource IS NULL
ORDER BY d.RECORDID DESC
```

or NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA1 d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DATA1 d0 WHERE d0.Project = d.PROJECT AND d0.Resource = 'I-FINAL')
ORDER BY d.RECORDID DESC
```

Neither has any guarantee to run faster. The thing that is most likely to be effective is evaluating indexes on the table, but we don't have enough info in the question to tell you what to change.

Comment: you mean WHERE d0.Project IS NULL instead of WHERE d0.Resourdce IS NULL . Is that right ?

Comment: @ELIP Is doesn't matter. Any non-null field would work

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need the subquery? Why not simply

```
SELECT * FROM DATA1 WHERE Resource != 'I-FINAL' ORDER BY RECORDID DESC
```

Comment: Because there might be `Data1` records where the `Resource` is not `I-FINAL`, but the `Project` value matches another record where the `Resource` is `I-FINAL`.